# Apply data frames to changing names in for loop

Tags: r, dataframe, for-loop

```
for(i in 1:length(file.list)){
 
 assign(paste("order_", i, sep = ""),i)  <- Data_cleaner(file.list[i])
 
}
}
```

I'm trying to apply the data frames to get new named separate data frames so that I can full join them afterwards and the function I made does work independently but I keep getting this error.

`Error in assign(paste("order_", i, sep = ""), i) <- Data_cleaner(file.list[i]) :  target of assignment expands to non-language object`

`file.list` is a file containing some text files that `Data_cleaner()` converts into text into data frames now i need to apply that to each txt file in `file.list`.

Any insights to what could be wrong would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed the issue by avoiding for loop and using `map` from purrr package

Answer (score 0):

`assign` already creates a variable (with the name defned by the first argument, and the content defined by the second), you don't need to use the `<-`, you can write only:

```
for(i in file.list){
    assign(paste("a", i, sep = ""), Data_cleaner(file.list[i]))}
```

But maybe there's a better way to "full join them", if you mean that they have the same columns and you want to merge their observations, you can simply do:

```
df = data.frame()
for(i in file.list){
    df = rbind(df, Data_cleaner(file.list[i]))}
```

If that's not exactly what you meant by joining them, tell me what is and i can try to adapt it.

Comment: `Error: file must be a string, raw vector or a connection.` `Data cleaner` outputs a data frame

Comment: I edited it, see if it worked. if you can, try posting a part of the data (see `?dput`) so we can run code with (if its too big, post just the first rows, or only a part of the list)

Comment: okay so `Data_cleaner` takes some text and turns it into a data frame and all the rows are different because not everyone orders the same items but all the columns are the same .

Comment: And you simply want to transform these several data frames (which are on `file.list`) into a large data frame with all the rows from all of those? If yes, then the second code should solve your problem more efficiently.